when I use fsanitize=safestack /usr/bin/ld: error hapen I compiled and installed the compiler-rt separately
when I use fsanitize=safestack /usr/bin/ld: error: cannot open /usr/local/lib/clang/16/lib/linux/libclang_rt.safestack-x86_64.a: No such file or directory, but /usr/local/lib/clang
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug       -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang       -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++       -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=YES       -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON       -DLLVM_CCACHE_BUILD=ON       -DLLVM_APPEND_VC_REV=OFF       -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="compiler-rt"   DLLVM_ENABLE_RUNTIMES="libcxx;libcxxabi;libunwind;compiler-rt" -DLIBCXX_USE_COMPILER_RT=YES  ../compiler-rt
that is my configure of cmake
